# SwiftUI ScrollView dynamic Height

Tags: swift, dynamic, height, swiftui

I currently have the problem that my scroll view does not automatically adjust to the height of the content. I think ASCollectionView is the one that causes the most problems at the moment. If I adjust the frame height manually (here e.g. 200 - see picture), then everything is visible. Of course I want to have it automatically. Do you have any idea how this could work?

I would be very happy! Have a nice afternoon.

Florian

[image]
[image]

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(self.collectionListViewModel.collections) { collection in
        NavigationLink(destination: GameListView()) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {

                // Name der Sammlung:
                Text(collection.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)

                // Optional: Für welche Konsolen bzw. Plattformen:
                ASCollectionView(data: collection.platforms, dataID: \.self) { item, _ in
                    Text("\(item)")
                        .fixedSize()
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 5)
                        .background(Color(.blue))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
                .layout {
                    let fl = AlignedFlowLayout()
                    fl.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
                    return fl
                }

            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
        }
        Divider()
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code to `ASCollectionView()`?

Comment: @krjw ASCollectionView() is a Framework that i use

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that ASCollectionView will (by default) take up however much room it is given. When nested in a ScrollView the amount of space available is undefined. You could set up the collectionView to automatically size itself to its content. An example is given in the [demo project here](https://github.com/apptekstudios/ASCollectionView/blob/master/Demo/ASCollectionViewDemo/Screens/Tags/TagsScreen.swift)

However, nesting scrollviews can cause difficulty, so I think the behaviour you're after would be more easily achieved by placing the title text as a section in the ASCollectionView.